# extract mysql queries from log files between tab spaces and newlines

Tags: mysql, formatting

i have a big log file having mysql logs. First is the timestamp of the query then the type i believe and then the actual query that has been made to the database.
and example is this

`2018-12-07T08:45:12.653298Z(tabspace)(more spaces here)493(space)Query(tabspace)SHOW TABLES FROM test_c(newline)`

the problem is that for big queries the log uses more (newlines) so 1 log of a query could span over several lines. So it would be something like the following

`2018-12-07T08:45:12.931589Z      22 Query SELECT nav
            FROM main_nav
            WHERE 'main/index' LIKE CONCAT(url, '%')
                OR '/main/index/' LIKE CONCAT(url, '%')
                OR '/main/index' LIKE CONCAT(url, '%')
                OR 'main/index' LIKE CONCAT(url, '%')
            ORDER BY LENGTH(url) DESC`

what i am trying to make is extract just the queries to a single file with every query in a single line and i am failing to make it happen.

Comment: which programming language do you use?

Comment: the application running is in php
i am trying though create that file i want using python

my initial approach was to make first a line every time i meet the tabspace and work from there, but it is not very efficient

Comment: i can give a piece of code that do the job in php

Comment: that may be helpful, i will try to convert it to python, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It search for the "keyword" " QUERY" . I tested with a log file created with the examples you provided in the question.
You have to replace the echo with the insertion in the table you want
Hope this help

```
<?php

    $f=fopen("logfile.log","r");
    $QueryFound=false;
    $ExtractedQuery='';
    while ($s=fgets($f)) {
        $SearchQueryKeyword=strpos($s," Query");
        if ($SearchQueryKeyword) {
            if ($QueryFound) {
                echo $ExtractedQuery."<br/><br/>";
            }
            $QueryFound=true;
            $ExtractedQuery=substr($s,$SearchQueryKeyword+6);
        }
        else {
            $ExtractedQuery.= $s;
        }
    }
    echo $ExtractedQuery;

    ?>
```